# in tradingview there is no "Message Box" in alert window , where is it?

Tags: tradingview-api

I discovered all the web! and I could not find why my alert window have no message box ??
even there is not a single email address of tradingview support for ask!

I want to place that a Json message, but it is missed!
[image]

[image]
please help

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you able to get messages to the discord now and if so how so lol ?

Answer (score 0):

I found it !

I must use `alertcondition()` instead of `alert()`